# Kibana Query Language(KQL)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to convert some regex to the kibana query's and I'm having trouble converting them;
this problem is also in the fallowing regex:
where the question mark can be any character([a-zA-Z0-9]) and the star can be any string characters.

```
\??-??\*.exe
```